# jquery window on load - prevent to display entire page before all background-image is loaded

Tags: jquery

i read and try every topic that i found, but i dont know why is not working.

i have 5 div with different background-image with large file. here my script.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<title>test</title>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">-->
<style>
*{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
.box{
 width:20%;
 border:1px solid #000;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height:100vh;
 float:left;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
}
.bg1{
background-image: url("https://artsandculture.withgoogle.com/gcs/national-parks-service/en-us/Asset-Kenai-desktop.jpg");
}
.bg2{
background-image: url("https://artsandculture.withgoogle.com/gcs/national-parks-service/en-us/Asset-Hawaii-desktop.jpg");
}
.bg3{
background-image: url("https://artsandculture.withgoogle.com/gcs/national-parks-service/en-us/de0b954d-ca76-41d3-ac3a-900c6bc25139.jpg");
}
.bg4{
background-image: url("https://artsandculture.withgoogle.com/gcs/national-parks-service/en-us/Asset-Bryce-desktop.jpg");
}
.bg5{
background-image: url("https://artsandculture.withgoogle.com/gcs/national-parks-service/en-us/Asset-Tortugas-desktop.jpg");
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="loading">LOADING</div>
<div class="container" style="display:none">
 <div class="box bg1"></div>
 <div class="box bg2"></div>
 <div class="box bg3"></div>
 <div class="box bg4"></div>
 <div class="box bg5"></div>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
alert('alert before dom ready');
$(function() {
 alert('dom ready');
 $('.loading').hide();
 $('.container').show();
 
});

</script>
</body></html>
```

once we run that script, browser will started to alert (alert before dom ready), but browser will immediately alert(dom ready) before my 5 background-images has loaded.

i tried $(window).on('load', function(){}), and $('.box').on('load', function(){}); but both not work for me.

what i want is show loading message/image before all my background-image has loaded

thanks for help

Comment: you want to show message before all image load or after all image load?

Comment: i want after all image load. sorry i was forgot to reply here. because i have some task on that day. btw thx for your attention my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code, Change the urls in array with your urls and write your code (which you want to call after all images) in callThisAfterAllImages.

```
function loadUrls(imgSrc, callBackAfterCheck) {
   var img = new Image();
   img.onload = function() { callBackAfterCheck(img ) };
   img.src = imgSrc;
 }

 var urlArray =   [{bgImage:'url1'},{bgImage:'url2'},{bgImage:'url3'},{bgImage:'url4'}];


var imageIndex = 0;
function callBackAfterCheck(img){
   imageIndex++
  $('.bg'+imageIndex).css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')');
   if(imageIndex < urlArray.length){
     var imageUrl = urlArray[imageIndex].bgImage;
     loadUrls(imageUrl, callBackAfterCheck)
   }else{
     callThisAfterAllImages();
   }
}

var imageUrl = urlArray[imageIndex].bgImage;
loadUrls(imageUrl, callBackAfterCheck);

function callThisAfterAllImages() {

}
```

Comment: 1. no elegant way to handle this. 2. your hack is awesome. thanks ^_^/

Answer (score 0):

Use `ready` function

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<title>test</title>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">-->
<style>
*{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
.box{
 width:20%;
 border:1px solid #000;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height:100vh;
 float:left;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
}
.bg1{
background-image: url("https://artsandculture.withgoogle.com/gcs/national-parks-service/en-us/Asset-Kenai-desktop.jpg");
}
.bg2{
background-image: url("https://artsandculture.withgoogle.com/gcs/national-parks-service/en-us/Asset-Hawaii-desktop.jpg");
}
.bg3{
background-image: url("https://artsandculture.withgoogle.com/gcs/national-parks-service/en-us/de0b954d-ca76-41d3-ac3a-900c6bc25139.jpg");
}
.bg4{
background-image: url("https://artsandculture.withgoogle.com/gcs/national-parks-service/en-us/Asset-Bryce-desktop.jpg");
}
.bg5{
background-image: url("https://artsandculture.withgoogle.com/gcs/national-parks-service/en-us/Asset-Tortugas-desktop.jpg");
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="loading">LOADING</div>
<div class="container" style="display:none">
 <div class="box bg1"></div>
 <div class="box bg2"></div>
 <div class="box bg3"></div>
 <div class="box bg4"></div>
 <div class="box bg5"></div>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
alert('alert before dom ready');
 
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert('dom ready');
 $('.loading').hide();
 $('.container').show();
});

</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: slow down your internet connection or make a lot of copy `http://domain.com/image.png?<?php time();?>` (prevent browser to use old cache) and you will know that is not work. btw, thx for your reply.

Comment: as i know, actually $(function() is same with $(document).ready. CMIIW

Comment: no problem , at least you try to help me. big thanks